# How to run the Visual Studio Debugger from the command line?

Tags: c, windows, debugging

I have built a C program (I downloaded the source code from the web) using the Microsoft Visual Stdio compiler. I am using the 2017 version of the Visual Studio . The code was compiled using make and running the compiler on the command line. Among the compiler flags used were:  /Od /Zi

I now want to use the Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger to step through my program. I do not know how to do this. I normally run the debugger from the development studio but I am not using the development stdio on this code. I am thinking if I knew the name of the executable I can then run the debugger from the command line. I do not however.

I am now thinking the following will start the debugger:
      devenv /debugexe

When I run it, I am not getting symbols. It says that it does not have a PDB file.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: @Ken White You are right, I will fix the post.

Comment: Note that you can also open executables from Visual Studio directly -- under "Open Project" you can choose "Exe files" in the filetype dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added these two flags to my link line:
/Od /Zi
Now the command:
devenv /debugexe
is working.